# Minimum dominating set $S$ where every vertex has a private neighbor outside of $S$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a set $S$ in a graph $G$ and a vertex $v \in S$, an $S$-external private neighbor of $v$ is a vertex outside $S$ that is adjacent to $v$ but to no other vertex of $S$ in $G$.

**I want to prove**:  *If $G$ is a graph with no isolated vertex, then there exists a minimum dominating set $S$ in $G$ with the property that every vertex of $S$ has an $S$-external private neighbor.*

**My Attempt**: Let $S_0$ be a minimum dominating set. Let $v \in S_0$ be a vertex with no external private neighbor. Let $u\in V \setminus S_0$ be s.t. $u \in N(v) \cap N(w)$, $w\in S_0$. Since $S_0$ is minimum-dom. set, then $v$ must be isolated in $G[S]$ (otherwise we could remove it and still maintain a dominating set). Then take $S_1 = S_0-v+u$. Continue  the process with $S_1$.

Now, I want to say that this process will terminate since the vertices once entering the active dominating set can't be removed from it, since they are **not** isolated in $G[S_i]$, for the respective $i$. And thus, at the end we get a $S_k (k \leq n)$ which is a min. dominating set with the required property.

Comment: Your **title** says that every vertex has exactly one neighbor outside of $S$, but that is not your question.

Comment: I didn't say every vertex has **exactly one neighbor**. outside of S. Nevertheless, I have changed it to something more suitable.

Comment: You said every vertex has **a unique neighbor** outside of $S$.

Comment: Yes, I meant "private" by that (didn't want to write private for some reason). Lets end this thread here...the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have already proven what you wanted! One way to rigorously finish the proof: observe that at each step, $G[S_{i+1}]$ is the graph $G[S_i]$ with an isolated vertex removed and a new vertex added with a few edges incident on it. This means that the number of edges in $G[S_i]$ is a strictly increasing function of $i$, while the number of vertices is invariant. Thus, the process must terminate.

Comment: That's a good observation!